# Android activity opening in background Instead on top in Accessibility Service

Tags: java, android, mobile, service

I have an Accessibility Service for a Screen Time Control app, which monitors and detects the launch of an user configured app for screen time control. The problem with this is that the activity is expected to open on top of that app to restrict the user to enter that app, but instead it is opening in background and the restricted app continues to open.

```
public class AppAccessibilityService extends android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService {
   private static final String TAG = "Accessibilty service";
   private static final String PREFS_NAME = "AppPrefs";

   private static final String KEY_LAST_APP_PACKAGE = "lastAppPackage";

   private SharedPreferences preferences;
   private UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager;

   @Override
   public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
       if (preferences == null) {
           preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
       }

       long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       UsageEvents usageEvents = usageStatsManager.queryEvents(
               preferences.getLong("lastAppCheckTime", currentTime - 1000), currentTime);

       while (usageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
           UsageEvents.Event usageEvent = new UsageEvents.Event();
           usageEvents.getNextEvent(usageEvent);
           Log.d( TAG, "Event:"+ usageEvent.getEventType());
           if (usageEvent.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND ) {
               String packageName  = usageEvent.getPackageName();

               Log.d(TAG, "Usage Event - Package Name: " + packageName);
               Log.d(TAG, "Usage Event - Package Name: " + usageEvent.getEventType());

               Log.d(TAG, "Last App Package: " + getLastAppPackage());
               Set<String> configuredApps = preferences.getStringSet("configuredApps",new HashSet<>());
               Log.d(TAG, configuredApps.toString());
               Log.d(TAG, "Package Name: " + packageName);
               Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(event.getEventType()));


               if(configuredApps.contains(packageName) && !configuredApps.contains(getLastAppPackage()) && !getLastAppPackage().equals("com.android.mindful")){
                   Log.d(TAG, "Last App Package Before Delay: " + getLastAppPackage());
                   Intent intent = new Intent(this, AccessDelayActivity.class);
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                   startActivity(intent);

               }
               setLastAppPackage(packageName);

               preferences.edit().putLong("lastAppCheckTime", currentTime).apply();
           }
       }


   }

   @Override
   public void onInterrupt() {

   }

   @Override
   protected void onServiceConnected() {
       super.onServiceConnected();

       AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
       // Set the type of events that this service wants to listen to. Others
       // aren't passed to this service.
       info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED |
               AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED;



       // Set the type of feedback your service provides.
       info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_SPOKEN;



       info.notificationTimeout = 100;

       this.setServiceInfo(info);
       Log.d(TAG,"Service Connected");

       this.usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);

   }

   private void setLastAppPackage(String packageName) {
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
       editor.putString(KEY_LAST_APP_PACKAGE, packageName);
       editor.apply();
   }

   private String getLastAppPackage() {
       return preferences.getString(KEY_LAST_APP_PACKAGE, null);
   }



}
```